# Bootstrap Tooltip data[option] is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this function setup

```
var $this = $(this);
if (msg == null) { 
    $this.tooltip('destroy');

}
else
{
    $this.tooltip({'title': msg, 'placement': 'right', 'trigger': 'manual'});
    $this.tooltip('show');
}
```

The tooltip shows up fine, the the destroy line throws an error `data[option] is not a function`. If I change it to `tooltip('hide')` the tooltip hides itself, I just can't get it to remove itself. Can anyone help me sort this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't make a typo check if you use the latest version of Bootstrap's javascript plugins.

tooltip.js contains:

```
  // TOOLTIP PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var old = $.fn.tooltip

  $.fn.tooltip = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.tooltip')
      var options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('bs.tooltip', (data = new Tooltip(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }
```

In the case of `.tooltip('destroy');` The line `if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()` gives the error you mention if `Tooltip.prototype.destroy` not exists.

Comment: Do you have a solution to this problem I have this exact issue with the Bootstrap Tabcordion (using the collaspse Bootstrap lib). Tried most recent jQuery and Boostrap to no success.

Comment: Well, there was an error in the Tabccordion, so I fixed it https://github.com/aexmachina/tabcordion/pull/3

Answer (score 3):

I fix it by loading *jquery-ui.min.js* after *bootstrap.min.js*

Answer (score 0):

```
$this.tooltip('destroy'); //it use Bootsrap tooltip
```

Try call jQuery

```
$(this).$(jQuery).tooltip('destroy');


$.ui.tooltip()
```

or replace function

```
$.fn.tooltip = jQuery.ui.tooltip;
```